# I see some unknown containers in `docker ps`

Tags: docker

When I run `docker ps -a` I get a list of unknown containers, with weird names

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
744a1a910d9a        dpa:latest          "sh -c 'java $JAVA_O…"   16 seconds ago      Exited (1) 16 seconds ago                       data-pipeline-automation
7ae02b5f62b0        06f8a9fed1c7        "/bin/sh -c 'sh -c '…"   2 weeks ago         Exited (2) 2 weeks ago                          dazzling_tharp
d9461d601d37        25c5574bfe1a        "/bin/sh -c 'sh -c '…"   2 weeks ago         Exited (2) 2 weeks ago                          distracted_khorana
24e4f72731df        5e64cb808d91        "/bin/sh -c 'sh -c '…"   2 weeks ago         Exited (126) 2 weeks ago                        awesome_hypatia
b7cbb9c62ca8        5e64cb808d91        "/bin/sh -c 'sh -c '…"   2 weeks ago         Exited (2) 2 weeks ago                          youthful_snyder
9d1ac66a9d77        457a135e1fb5        "sh -c 'java $JAVA_O…"   4 weeks ago         Exited (1) 4 weeks ago                          automation
```

In this list the first and the last one are images I created and deployed, rest are unknown.
What do the other containers in this list mean? Should I be bothered about these?

Comment: I am also having same issue with my EC2 instance on aws, I tried to delete all container, all images but docker (or may be something else) keeps creating unknown containers. let me know if anyone have some clarification/solution to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your suspicousness comes from the strange names that those docker containers have, as e.g. `dazzling_tharp`: This is the naming scheme for docker containers that are created without the `--name` argument. The first part of the name is a random attribute, the second one a random noun.

E.g. `docker run <image>` will generate a random container name, while `docker run --name my-container <image>` will not.
So I would assume that you created these containers playing around with docker and not using the --name argument.

You can retrieve some information about a docker container by using `docker inspect <container-id>`. This will e.g. show you the creation date of the container and the args it was started with. A similar command exists for inspecting images: `docker inspect <image-id>`.

In my experience it can be very hard to trace where a docker container/image came from. This is one of the reasons you should **never give all users permissions to use the docker socket**, but only a privileged user group.

Answer (score 1):

No need to worry. These *are* containers that you have run, though, probably whilst testing/debugging something.

They can safely be deleted with `docker rm <container ID>`, or to clear them all, `docker rm $(docker ps -aq)`

Comment: how do you know that "these *are* containers that OP has run"? chances are that this is true, but you state it as a fact, which i think is just dangerous.

Comment: @umläute  <sigh> OK. Hey, OP, there is a 99.999% chance that these containers *were* run by you, either directly, or when experimenting with some other docker/docker-compose/(insert other container-based tech here). They were run two weeks ago (and aren't running now), there is very, very, (very), little chance that they are anything to worry about and they can be safely deleted. Maybe just keep an eye open to see if similar containers appear again, to be safe. 
Better?